# How to provide type hints for argparse arguments?

Tags: python, type-hinting, pylint, mypy, python-typing

I would like to get proper linting and type hints by [PyFlakes, Pylint] and mypy.

For example, in the following code, we cannot get type error for the last line.
We cannot even know if `float_input` exists.

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--float_input', type=float)
args = parser.parse_args()


def int_sum(a: int, b: int):
    return a + b

c = int_sum(args.float_input, args.float_input)
```

Is there a good way to improve this?

Comment: Make it required. The float constructor will also throw on invalid input. What about the current scenario is insufficient? Also why does the help for that float argument say it's a *file path*?

Comment: Oh sorry, the help was just a mistake.
However, required arguments also give the same result in my environment.

Comment: Please be aware that ["Is it a good practice...?" questions thend to be opinion-based?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296542/are-is-it-a-good-practice-questions-off-topic-or-opinion-based) and thus off-topic. You might want to [edit] the question to have a clearly defined goal – e.g. *specifically* how to annotate this to get a warning (?) for this situation – instead of inviting general descriptions of best practices. (I've just gone ahead and changed it – leaving up this comment FYI.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [typed-argument-parser](https://github.com/swansonk14/typed-argument-parser) to provide type hints for your arguments. You can define your arguments in a typesafe manner.

```
from typing import Optional
from tap import Tap

class FooArgumentParser(Tap):
    float_input: Optional[float] = None

args = FooArgumentParser().parse_args()


def int_sum(a: int, b: int):
    return a + b


c = int_sum(args.float_input, args.float_input)
c = int_sum(args.foo, args.bar)
```

which gives you:

```
foo.py:13:13: error: Argument 1 to "int_sum" has incompatible type "Optional[float]"; expected "int"
foo.py:13:31: error: Argument 2 to "int_sum" has incompatible type "Optional[float]"; expected "int"
foo.py:14:13: error: "FooArgumentParser" has no attribute "foo"
foo.py:14:23: error: "FooArgumentParser" has no attribute "bar"
```

For required arguments, note that:

> Variables defined as name: type are required arguments while variables defined as name: type = value are not required and default to the provided value.

You have to give the argument a default value to make it optional.

Comment: If there's other approaches that are less invasive, I'm all ears (as a library mainainer). This isn't vanilla `argparse`, it's a third party dependency in parity with it. The other issue is it's not merely a mypy plugin (this can't be dev dependency), it's a runtime package, with all the costs, potential bugs, etc. For me, this negates the benefit standard library argparse and annotations.